# Kettle 9.2 is not able to establish connection with mysql

Tags: mysql, pentaho, kettle

```
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : A serious error occurred during job execution:
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Communications link failure
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Communications link failure
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:497)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:389)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:360)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:350)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.beginProcessing(Job.java:987)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:477)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:389)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Communications link failure
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:605)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:481)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  ... 6 more
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:589)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  ... 7 more
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 - The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818)
2023/09/13 17:21:30 - ant_pfteam_vs_prodazi1 -  ... 13 more
```

I have fixed the .jar file which was one of the solution given but still in vain

Comment: You fixed the jar file?  Explain.

Comment: Yes, this looks like a driver issue. Please confirm if you are using the right version of MYSQL driver. Pentaho 9.2 supports version 5 and 8. [Check here for the supported drivers](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.2/Setup/JDBC_drivers_reference#r_pentaho_my_sql_jdbc_drivers_reference). Also it would be best to test the database connectivity before executing the PDI job.

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar

Comment: I tried with version 5 and 8 before. but still the smae problem

Comment: in kettle PDI im able to connect to database. but from an ubuntu machine when i launch the script it throws this error

Comment: This looks like the firewall port of the database from the ubuntu machine is not open. Please open the MySQL port 3306 (default) / or the port which you are using in ubuntu.[How to open firewall port in ubuntu](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-open-firewall-port-on-ubuntu-linux-12-04-14-04-lts/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already enable it